# почему при загрузке страницы текст не появляется

Tags: javascript, html

мне нужно чтобы при загрузке страницы текст плавно появлялся, но я попробовал сделать это на тестовом html документе, все работает. В чем проблема?

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
ol,
ul,
li {
    list-style: none;
}

img {
    vertical-align: top;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
}


body {
  background-image: url(/images/backImg.svg);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.how-it-work {
  color: #fff;
}

.text {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.main {
  font-size: 5.8rem;
}

.second {
  font-size: 3.4rem;
}

.third {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.textSpace {
  padding-top: 6rem;
}



.burger {
  display: none;
}


.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

div {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="hidden">
      <div class="container">
        <header class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-md-between py-3 mb-4">
          <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center col-md-3 mb-2 mb-md-0 text-dark text-decoration-none">
            <img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="" width="90" height="82">
          </a>
      
          <ul class="full nav col-12 col-md-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
            <div class="full"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info how-it-work text-white">Как все устроено?</button></div>
          </ul>
    
          <div class="full col-md-3 text-end">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary me-2 text-white">Login</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-white">Sign-up</button>
          </div>

          <div class="burger">
            <ul class="nav col-12 col-md-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info how-it-work text-white">Как все устроено?</button>
            </ul>
      
            <div class="col-md-3 text-end">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary me-2 text-white">Login</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-white">Sign-up</button>
            </div>
          </div>


        </header>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="hidden">
      <div class="container textSpace">
        <h1 class="main text">ТВОЙ ПОМОЩНИК</h1>
        <h3 class="second text">В УЧЕБЕ</h3>
        <h5 class="third text">учись создавай открывай</h5>
      </div>
    </section>
    
</body>
<script>
  window.onload() = function() {
    document.querySelector("section").classList.remove('hidden');
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Пишет же ошибку window.onload is not a function

Comment: Скобки у onload уберите

Comment: И обязательно для этого js использовать? css animation нельзя реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так нельзя реализовать? Но есть минус, неизвестно время загрузки страницы, поэтому и непонятно сколько нужен delay перед началом анимации.

```css
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showSection 1s 1s forwards linear;
}

@keyframes showSection {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="hidden">
  <div class="container textSpace">
    <h1 class="main text">ТВОЙ ПОМОЩНИК</h1>
    <h3 class="second text">В УЧЕБЕ</h3>
    <h5 class="third text">учись создавай открывай</h5>
  </div>
</section>
```